# Can't use Facebook Account Kit: Error inflating class com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ConstrainedLinearLayout

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook AccountKit to allow users to sign-up with their e-mail or phone number. But when launching the AccountKitActivity, the app crash because it can't inflate a "ConstrainedLayout".

Error message :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: 
Error inflating class com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ConstrainedLinearLayout
```

And below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
   Failed to resolve attribute at index 12: 
   TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x512 "res/drawable/scrollbar_handle_material.xml" a=1 r=0x10805cd}
```

I'm using in my gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.11.0'
```

I'm calling AccountKit.initialize() before trying to launch the AccountKitActivity.

My simple login activity, made of two buttons:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button buttonSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignInSms);
        Button buttonEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignInEmail);

        buttonSMS.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public static int APP_REQUEST_CODE = 42;

    public void onLoginPhone(final View view) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountKitActivity.class);
        AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
                new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                        LoginType.PHONE,
                        AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE); // or .ResponseType.TOKEN
        // ... perform additional configuration ...
        intent.putExtra(
                AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
                configurationBuilder.build());
        startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void onLoginEmail(final View view) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountKitActivity.class);
        AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
                new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                        LoginType.EMAIL,
                        AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE); // or .ResponseType.TOKEN
        // ... perform additional configuration ...
        intent.putExtra(
                AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
                configurationBuilder.build());
        startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonSignInSms : {
                onLoginPhone(v);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.buttonSignInEmail : {
                onLoginEmail(v);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone as an idea?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I ran in to this exact same problem today integrating Account Kit.  Their documentation isn't explicit on this, but you need to add the AppLoginTheme to your themes.xml:

```
<style name="AppLoginTheme" parent="Theme.AccountKit" />
```

Another possible solution is to remove the theme override for the AccountKitActivity in the manifest like so:

```
...
<activity android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity" />
...
```

Comment: You brought my faith into Stackoverflow back. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing!  Glad I could help :)

Comment: What if I want to use custom theme which is similar to my color theme?

Comment: @DharmendraPratapSingh I believe you would have your custom theme inherit Theme.AccountKit as its parent.  From there you can set your color theme accordingly.  There should be specific XML properties you can use to mimic your color scheme.  Follow this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing) for more details.

Comment: still getting same error on Lenovo TAB 2 A7-30HC (5.0.1)
i put <activity android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity" /> in manifest

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. Zac's solution helped me to solve the problem. Below is my solution and this may be helpful for somebody else.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.screenshot.accountkitclient">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity"
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            android:theme="@style/AppLoginTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/ak_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

> Don't forget to add tools:replace="android:theme" in the AccountKitActivity

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppLoginTheme" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_color">#ef0414</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_text_color">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_secondary_text_color">#f10910</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_status_bar_color">#e40416</item>

    <item name="com_accountkit_input_accent_color">?attr/com_accountkit_primary_color</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_border_color">?attr/com_accountkit_primary_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

don't do hacks! Just download the latest **Facebook SDK**, unzip the file and find in the folder **facebook-android-sdk-4.20.0\AccountKit** the file **account-kit-sdk-4.20.0.aar**. Change the extension of the .aar file to zip and unzip this accout-kit-sdk file. Go the the folder **res\values** and copy the **values.xml** file to your project res/values directory. Voila!