# facebook account kit - Returns error "We're sorry, something went wrong." in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am implementing facebook account kit in android app. I've completed initial setup and when I run the app it displays error

> We're sorry, something went wrong.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android

I searched a lot but did not find anything helpful. 
If anyone has something to share please share here.

Comment: Could you add in your code for the implementation/setup to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: I found this video regarding account kit integration which solved my errors - https://youtu.be/o2-PCiiJzr4

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it? Please help! Thank you

Comment: <href a="Click here"> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718119/cant-use-facebook-account-kit-error-inflating-class-com-facebook-accountkit-ui/36820477</href> may it help you!!!!!

Comment: Could you post a detailed log cat?

Answer (score 5):

You need to go through link
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/    ----Your-App-ID---    /account-kit/

you can see Enable client access token flow. 
make it yes.

Answer (score 2):

@JayVDiyk You can get more information for an error by setting the `debug` flag of the `init` method to `true`, for more information about the reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webjs/reference

The way you could set `init` method to `true`:

`AccountKit.init({appId: 1, state: state, version: 'v1.0', debug: true})`

Else you could try the solution by adding the `http://localhost:3000'` like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set up the Account kit properly. The error shows with incorrect setup in my case.

steps are:

1. Generate Key Hash
2. Create a Facebook App.
3. Add Account Kit to your Facebook App 
   [image][image][image]
4. Android Integration

   a. Gradle Dependencies

Add dependency in gradle for Account Kit

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
}
```

b. Android Manifest

Add the following to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ApplicationName" android:value="@string/app_name" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken" android:value="@string/account_kit_client_token" />

<activity
 android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity"
 android:theme="@style/AppLoginTheme"
 tools:replace="android:theme"/>
```

Please Go through this links:

1) [Link 1](http://www.vishweshshetty.com/facebook-account-kit-sms-authentication-android-tutorial-demo-sample/)

2) [Link 2](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-passwordless-authentication-with-account-kit--cms-28033)

Comment: In my case, it only happens on iPad exclusively.